Create a variable to bring multiple values from another table
I am trying to create a webi report from a universe
I have creates two queries.
The data in query 1 has the following data



ID
Name




1
Tom


2
Brad


3
George


4
Adam



The data in query 2 has the following data



ID
FID
Food




1
1
Pasta


2
1
Bread


3
1
Rice


4
2
Pasta


5
3
Fries


6
3
Noodles


7
4
Bread


6
4
Soup



My report is based off query 1. However I would also like to bring in the related values in a column called colors like below.



ID
Product
Foods




1
Tom
Pasta, Bread, Rice


2
Brad
Pasta, Rice


3
George
Noodles


4
Adam
Bread, Soup



I have a merged dimension between name.id and food.fid
I have created a variable called "Foods which has the following formula in it.
  =Min([Food]) + ", " + Max([Food])

This works for two foods, but doesn't pick up a third or fourth. Can anyone advise a more elegant formula that would take into multiple records without the #MultiValue appearing? I've been looking at index() Foreach but can't get anything to work.
TIA
